# how to convert this python function norm.cdf into pyspark in aws glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Below in the code I have tried

```
norm_cdf = f.udf(lambda x: float(norm.cdf(x)))

output = output.withColumn('SS_INPUT_SERVICE_LEVEL',
f.when(f.col('SS_INPUT_KFACTOR').isNotNull(),
                            f.round(norm_cdf(output['SS_INPUT_KFACTOR']),8))).show()
```

But this is throwing me Python exception

Please help me in this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.